# Use Func animation python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The following code has been taken from [here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) and modified to fit my requirements:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import math
import linecache
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,600), ylim=(0,600))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3, color='r')
mul=2*math.pi/3
samp_rate=10
print ax
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    print i
    global mul
    global samp_rate
    line1=linecache.getline("data.txt", i+1)
    if i==0:
        x = float(line1)*math.cos(0)
        y = float(line1)*math.sin(0)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,
    else:
        x=float(line1)*math.cos((i)*mul/samp_rate)
        y=float(line1)*math.cos((i)*mul/samp_rate)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=5, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

On printing ax the output given is as follows:

`Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)`

I set the values from 0 to 600 but the limit is `0.775 to 0.8`? Why is this so?
Also, the values that I am plotting are from 100 to 400 and the output window is:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

I changed the code a bit. Now I input values from a list, i.e., I am not opening a file for the values I am just creating a list with the values. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import math
import linecache
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,600), ylim=(0,600))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3, color='r')
mul=2*math.pi/3
samp_rate=10
print ax

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    print i
    global mul
    global samp_rate
    line1=linecache.getline("data.txt", i+1)
    x=[some vlaues that I have to plot]
    y=[some vlaues that I have to plot]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    i+=1
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=200,interval=24,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

In this case the output is as follows:
[image]

Also as I am printing the value of `i` as soon as I enter function animate the output provided is constantly increasing.

I have supplied about 20k values for x and the same amount of values for y. As you can see in the screen shot it not plotting all of them. How do I plot all the points?

Answer (score 0):

`print(ax)` doesn't give you the x and y limits. It gives you the position of the axis in the figure. `print` uses the method `__str__`. In IPython you can see the documentation for a method using:

```
In [16]: ax.__str__??
Source:
    def __str__(self):
        return "Axes(%g,%g;%gx%g)" % tuple(self._position.bounds)
```

You can also get the position of the axes with:

```
In[4]:ax._position.bounds
Out[4]: (0.125, 0.099999999999999978, 0.77500000000000002, 0.80000000000000004)
```

To get the x and y limits of the axes use:

```
In[2]: ax.get_ylim()
Out[2]: (0.0, 600.0)

In[3]: ax.get_xlim()
Out[3]: (0.0, 600.0)
```

I'm not sure why lines lines aren't showing up with out seeing the contents of data.txt. I'd suggest checking that `line1` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I debugged and found that `line1` is what I expected. What else can go wrong?